# What template engine does Koha use to render ISBD views?

Tags: templating, marc

I'm looking for a way to introduce some logic in rendering ISBD views in Koha (Open Source integrated library system). The views are configurable, but I can't really find any information about the syntax, and whether or not some basic logic can be incorporated in the templates.
Any help is appreciated.

Here's a snippet of what a template looks like:

`#245||{ 245a }{ 245b }{245f }{ 245g }{ 245k }{ 245n }{ 245p }{ 245s }{ 245h }|`

The structure is the following : #tagNumber|| {tagNumber+subfieldCode} |

Tried looking the documentation but couldn't find anything.